# How I use if else condition in my get_file_contents which I grab from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am displaying contents from the text file from database through file_get_contents.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myContent";
$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);


$file = file_get_contents('mytext.txt');
echo $file;
```

Everything fine, but when my file is missing I get errors. How I put if-else condition in my php code when file is missed or not in place. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
if(file_exists('mytext.txt')) {
    $file = file_get_contents('mytext.txt');
    echo $file;
}
```

Comment: This is the most appropriate way to handle this thing.  As file_get_contents doesn't throw an exception but throw an error, so it cannot be handle by try catch

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps ;)

```
if(!empty(file_get_contents('mytext.txt'))):
    // Display file contents
else:
   // Error handling
endif;
```

Comment: Will always throw an error if file doesn't exists

Comment: @JessGabriel no it doesn't, i tried and tested it before posting the solution.

Comment: function `file_get_contents()` itself will throw an error before the `empty()` function is executed.